# Understanding the Diewertt Cost Function

Tags: microeconomics, cost-functions

The Diewert cost function (as described in [Microeconomic Analysis by Hal Varian 3rd Edition](http://virtualpanic.com/anonymousftplistings/ebooks/ECONOMICS/Economics.Microeconomic%20Analysis%203d%20Hal%20Varian.pdf)) takes the form of:

$$c(w,y)=y\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^kb_{ij}\sqrt{w_iw_j}$$

Varian goes on to say (page 209)

> For this functional form, we require that $b_{ij}=b_{ji}$. Note we can also write this form as:
>   $$c(w,y)=y\left[\sum_{i=1}^kb_{ii}w_i+\sum_{i\neq j}\sum_{j \neq i}b_{ij}\sqrt{w_iw_j}\right]$$
>   Since the first part of the equation has the form of a Leontief cost function. this form is also known as a **generalized  Leontief cost function**.

What phenomenon is this cost function coming to describe? Is there an example of what this cost function represents?

Comment: Relevant: http://darp.lse.ac.uk/PapersDB/Diewert_(JPE71).pdf